# go type-switch how to deal with point to nil

Tags: go, pointers, type-switch

like this, if msg point to null value, how to deal with it  in **clean code**

```
func test(a SomeType) {
    switch msg := a.(type) {
    case *type1:
        dosomething1(a)
    case *type2:
        dosomething2(a)
    case *type3:
        dosomething3(a)
    default:
        do()
}
```

the main func may be this

```
func main() {
    var b_ptr *stTest
    aa := interface{}(b)
    test(aa)
}

type test struct {
    c int
    d string
}
```

b_ptr is a pointer, but it point to nil, i want to judge it in test func
if i use b_ptr in test func, eg: print a.c  or a.d, it will crash.

i do it by this way. do if(), everywhere use a, but it too stupid.

```
func test(a SomeType) {
    switch msg := a.(type) {
    case *type1:
        if msg == nil {
            return
        }
        dosomething1(a)
    case *type2:
        if msg == nil {
            return
        }
        dosomething2(a)
    case *type3:
        if msg == nil {
            return
        }
        dosomething3(a)
    default:
        do()
}
```

Comment: Type assertion returns a second return value (type bool), do the switch case only if its true

Comment: You can use `case nil:`, or have an `if a == nil { return }` above the switch. However if you are trying to deal with non-nil interface values that hold a typed `nil` pointer then the problem is with the caller. Passing around such values is bad practice.

Comment: Your current approach is the most clean in my opinion. It's the least verbose approach which doesn't use reflect and I would expect it will perform better than reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this ought to be considered a problem with the caller, and therefore it should be the caller's job to deal with the fallout. Passing around non-nil interfaces that hold nil values is bad practice unless it's intentional/expected.

If you can't avoid the non-nil interface with nil-pointer however, then you can use `reflect` to check if the underlying value is `nil`.

```golang
func test(a SomeType) {
    if rv := reflect.ValueOf(a); !rv.IsValid() || rv.IsNil() {
        return
    }
    switch msg := a.(type) {
    case *type1:
        dosomething1(a)
    case *type2:
        dosomething2(a)
    case *type3:
        dosomething3(a)
    default:
        do()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I understand that my way is also feasible??? And I think reflect is slower than ```if msg == nil {return}```      Is my understanding correct？

Comment: Yes it works, but wasn't your question about how to avoid doing that in each `case`'s block?

Comment: yes, only use reflect can avoid it, thanks very much